# JavaScript PayPal Variable Price

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal, parse-platform, firebase

I'm working on a ecommerce-type plugin for my website and I'm using PayPal to deal with the transactions. 
So I followed the guide to create a "Buy Now" button on the [website](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/buy-now-button) and I got the form that works great:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id"> ....
```

However I just have a question in terms of how I can tweak this plugin:

I have variables that contain the price of the items on my website so something like `var price1 = 10;` and these variables automatically change themselves based on changes I make on my website. (I'm using Firebase as the backend for this). So I wanted to know if it was possible to have the prices for each item updated automatically on PayPal directly with JavaScript or some API (like Firebase or Parse).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd really like to refrain from using PHP if possible!

Comment: I've used Paypal's "[upload](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/)" method before to build pure javascript checkouts. You lose a lot of the neat tracking that the "hosted button" method provides, but it will allow you to have variable prices. Here is an example in action. I'm manipulating hidden form fields with javascript.  http://www.wamegofireworks.com/sponsor/donate

Comment: If it's all `client side` how would data be secured/protected from tampering?

Comment: @ClaytonLeis isn't that insecure? I edited the html and changed the value and submitted the form and PayPal changed the value: http://i.imgur.com/r1KTKCq.png

Comment: @EdSF I'm looking for some kind of API that would allow me to do this. So far I've found Zapier that would allow me to combine both Firebase (which I am already using) and PayPal to receive transactions so I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: Yes, it requires human processes on the back end of it.